# I want to receive all users message using smack(Not in Group Chat)

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

**I am creating a chat application ,one to one chatting is working properly ,but when comes to multi user chat i am not able to listen their messages
I am using smack for implementing the XMPP protocol
Here is the code**

> Server configuration part is

```
    public void serverCongig() throws XMPPException {
     
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Initializing connection to server %1$s port 
       %2$d", server, port));
    SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);
    config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, 
        port,PropertyReader.getPropertiesValue("server_domain"));
 //        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
     
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    try
    {
       connection.connect();
        LOGGER.info("Connected: " + connection.isConnected()+" Service 
         name"+connection.getServiceName());
        chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
        messageListener = new MyMessageListener();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
                    callThread();
     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      finally
    {
        callThread();
    }
   
     
}
```

**Message listening part is**
class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

```
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        try
        {
        String from = message.getTo();
        String body = message.getBody();
        String toUser="";
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
        String[] user=from.split("@");
        for(int i=0;i<user.length;i++)
         toUser=user[0];
        LOGGER.info("Receiver Phone number"+toUser); 
        SendMsgToWhatsapp create=new SendMsgToWhatsapp();
        try {
            if(!body.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
            {
              create.processWhatsappMessage(toUser, body);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            callThread();
```

//                Logger.getLogger(XmppManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
callThread();
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and that's what I found:
XEP-0313: Message Archive Management (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) describes to work with the message archive.

In smack you can use it like that

```
  MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        MamManager.MamQueryArgs mamQueryArgs = MamManager.MamQueryArgs.builder()
                .limitResultsToJid(jid)
                .setResultPageSizeTo(10)
                .queryLastPage()
                .build();
        MamManager.MamQuery mamQuery = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs);
        List<Message> messages = mamQuery.getMessages();

        for (Message m : messages) {
            System.out.println(m.getBody());
        }
```

But when I tried to use it, I received problems with dependencies in maven, so I loaded smack jar manually from dailybuilds (https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/dailybuilds/smack-SNAPSHOT-2020-07-21.zip) and the remaining dependencies added through maven

In my case it work.

https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/mam/package-summary.html (smackx.mam javadoc)